# iPad Splitter - Popup Tint

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to tint my UI to a nice brown. The pop up associated with the splitter is blackish-blue. How do I change its tint to the one I have applied to the rest of the app?

Here's a picture:

[image]

When I change the tint in IB it then looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the border can not be changed from the grey color..only the title. You need to set the tintcolor property on the navigation bar.

myController.navigationBar.tintColor

Comment: The controller that holds the Master view. You can also set the color  in interface builder.

Comment: String, I do. Perhaps it's in the framework I am using.   public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
 this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = Colors.Tint;
}

Comment: You're using monotouch? I accomplished this by setting the value in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes, Monotouch. But when I set the tint in UI Builder, it appears all white when run. Looks fine though in UI Builder.

Comment: What color are you setting it to? Colors.Tint? I don't think that is a real color...

Comment: Colors.Tint is a static class that holds my settings. I'll add a photo of what the white looks like.

Comment: Try setting it to something like this: UIColor.FromRGB(145, 35, 35); and see if it works.